# SQL - convert month string '08-2019' to timestamp datatype - 01-08-2019

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column - local_month - containing a string value "2019-08". Any ideas how I can convert this to a timestamp datatype?

My current approach was to get substrings of the value to yield a value of 01-08-2019. This still is giving me an error when I try to use it as  a timestamp.

```
FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%d-%m-%Y",TIMESTAMP(DATE(cast(SUBSTR(local_month,1,4) as int64),cast(SUBSTR(local_month,6,2) as int64),cast('01' as int64)))) as month
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above functions are product specific.)

Comment: I'm not sure what flavour sql it is. I think 'Standard SQL'. I'm using Google Cloud's documentation https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp

Comment: What is the error you are getting when running the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `PARSE_DATE` and then cast the output to timestamp as `PARSE_DATE` will return a `DATE`:

```
with parse_date AS (SELECT PARSE_DATE("%m-%Y", '08-2019') as date)

SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%d-%m-%Y', CAST(date as TIMESTAMP)) from parse_date
```

Which will output the following:

```
Row |   f0_ 
------------------
1   |   01-08-2019
```

More information about `PARSE_DATE` function can be found in the [public docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date).

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of the `PARSE_()` functions.  In your case, `PARSE_TIMESTAMP()`:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%m-%Y', '08-2019'),
       PARSE_DATETIME('%m-%Y', '08-2019'),
       PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%m-%Y', '08-2019')
```